Python: NameError from np.complex() numpy
I'm trying to run the program from project https://github.com/erikkaashoek/tinySA-saver
and I'm getting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\foo\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.12.2\Scripts\TinySASaver.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\foo\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.12.2\Lib\site-packages\TinySASaver\__main__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .TinySASaver import TinySASaver
  File "C:\Users\foo\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.12.2\Lib\site-packages\TinySASaver\TinySASaver.py", line 36, in <module>
    from .Calibration import CalibrationWindow, Calibration
  File "C:\Users\foo\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.12.2\Lib\site-packages\TinySASaver\Calibration.py", line 815, in <module>
    class Calibration:
  File "C:\Users\foo\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.12.2\Lib\site-packages\TinySASaver\Calibration.py", line 834, in Calibration
    shortIdeal = np.complex(-1, 0)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\foo\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.12.2\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 338, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(__former_attrs__[attr])
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'complex'.
`np.complex` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `complex`. To avoid this error in existing code, use `complex` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.complex128` here.
The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance see the original release note at:
    https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations. Did you mean: 'complex_'?

So naturally I tried changing line 834 of [Calibration.py](https://github.com/erikkaashoek/tinysa-saver/blob/master/TinySASaver/Calibration.py) to complex_(-1, 0) but I get another error.
I have tried everything at AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'complex' and the link there.
I have tried:
complex(
complex_(
complex128(
np.complex(
np.complex_(
np.complex128(

I either get the above error or TypeError: function takes at most 1 argument (2 given) or NameError: name 'complex128' is not defined. Did you mean: 'complex'?.
EDIT: I should mention that the attributes within the parentheses printed by the CLI often differ from those above or from the file itself.
EDIT: plain complex(-1, 0) was the answer

Are you sure you tried plain complex(-1, 0)? That should have worked.

(You'll need to fix the other 25 places that file tries to use np.complex too, of course.)

There are 20+ occurrences  of np.complex in Calibration.py. Changing only first one will not fix the problem.

user235711212 Thank you! Turn yours into an Answer so I can give you credit.

I had changed the two on my screen, but had missed the change from "line 844" to "line 856" etc. to realize I had more to change.

Now I get ...\.pyenv\pyenv-win\...\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 639, in http_error_default raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp) urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404. If I change line 515 to sys.audit('requests.get(url)', req.full_url, req.data, req.headers, req.get_method()) as in /questions/42441211/ I get  \site-packages\requests\compat.py", line 66, in <module> from urllib.request import (ImportError: cannot import name 'getproxies' from partially initialized module 'urllib.request' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\...\.pyenv\pyenv-win\...\urllib\request.py)
